# Codeigniter: Missing argument 1 for Autoloader::autoloader()

Tags: php, codeigniter, autoloader

I've been trying to autoload my core classes by adding the autoload function under beneath the config file, with no result. Now I'm trying to get it to work using hooks, but unfortunately with the same negative result. When I try to output the filepath within the foreach I receive the following paths:

```
application/core/CI_Utf8.phpapplication/core/CI_URI.phpapplication/core/CI_Router.phpapplication/core/CI_Output.phpapplication/core/CI_Security.phpapplication/core/CI_Input.phpapplication/core/CI_Lang.phpapplication/core/CI_Loader.phpapplication/core/CI_DB.phpapplication/core/CI_DB.php
```

Could someone please share with me what I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance

```
    $hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'class' => 'Autoloader',
    'function' => 'register',
    'filename' => 'Autoloader.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params' => array(APPPATH.'core/')
);

$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'class' => 'Autoloader',
    'function' => 'register',
    'filename' => 'Autoloader.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params' => array(APPPATH.'controllers/')
);
```

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); 
    class Autoloader {

        private $_include_paths = array();


        public function register(array $paths = array())
        {   
            $this->_include_paths = $paths;

            spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'autoloader'));
        }


        public function autoloader($class)
        {   
            foreach($this->_include_paths as $path)
            {
                $filepath = $path . $class . EXT;



                if(!class_exists($class, FALSE) AND is_file($filepath))
                {
                    include_once($filepath);
                    echo $filepath;
                    break;
                }       
            }

        }
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: $this keyword here points to the AutoLoader class, you'll need to &get_instance of the codeigniter's class & load your stuffs into it.

Answer (score 0):

try 2 dimensional array...

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
                            'class'    => '',
                            'function' => 'load_config',
                            'filename' => 'load_config.php',
                            'filepath' => 'hooks'
                            );

$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
                            'class'    => '',
                            'function' => 'load_shops',
                            'filename' => 'load_shops.php',
                            'filepath' => 'hooks'
                            );
```

Comment: there is other way to autoload class in codeigniter. 1>create library under application/library. you can autoload library using config/autoload.php